# Junit & Mockito for android framework - Unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to use Junit & Mockito for android framework java files for local unit testing.
I am not using android studio and want to write these unit testcases and execute them on Linux server.
I have used libraries Junit, Mockito , hamcrest-core jar files. Do I need to include any other jar files?
I am stuck at mocking the context.
@Mock Context context  - Doesn't work at all 
Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Can you provide some code?

Comment: Hi, I included framework.jar in the classpath and works well now. I have a problem in compiling files from different packages. There is a cyclic dependency among the files. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: it is very difficult to guide you anywhere without having the code or dependency tree.

Comment: there are totally 11 packages and these 11 packages are having cyclic dependency. 
I have taken the path of all the java files using find . -name *.java > source.txt . 

javac -c classpath @source.txt . 
Because of cyclic dependency, we are getting errors in compilation

Comment: can i have any links beside developers.android.com for a beginners on testing using JUnit and Mockito.. i tried googling but still i am confused.

Comment: you can refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/